# Outsystems platform: getting FullContact details for a person

Tags: social-networking, outsystems

I have been doing a work in `outsystems` platform.

My works is a recruitment application where you add candidates to your app with a curriculum. You then choose the best ones to schedule an interview with, and eventually you can hire them to your company. Well, I don't known if you guys really need to know what my app is about, or what it does but I can explain better or eventually show it if it helps with my problem.

Well what I want is:
- When I register a candidate, I add a name, an email address, and a phone number. With this email, `Outsystems` offers a widget that can find all networks referred to that person (by email), that widget (I am not sure if this is the correct name for this tool, maybe API is more correct) can be found in Logic and inside the folder called Dependencies, that widget is called `FullContact`. To use that API you must create a new action. I did it and I filled the mandatory parameters called `Email` with `Candidate Email`. I am not sure what to put in `APIKey` parameter, I tried a lot of things and when I publish and test it I always have the same error called `403 Forbidden`. What I am doing wrong?

I am not sure if this question is supposed to be done here, if it is not just tell me and I can delete the question and search somewhere else.

what I have is this: [app print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKERD.png)
I am not sure what to put in APIkey, I saw an example and the person that did it added an assign and an ajax refresh. Do I need it to? And this is the error I get when I test the app [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nokW.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never worked with FullContact before but from some researches I learned the following:

**Overview:** The FullContact Developer APIs are used to manage and enhance contact information.

**Authentication:** All requests to all endpoints require you to specify your unique API key. The API Key is assigned to you by FullContact and is used to identify and authorize each request. Your API key should be kept private, and should never be displayed publicly.

To signup and get your free trial: https://portal.fullcontact.com/signup

**Note:** FullContact isn't free, you can only apply for a trial or pay.

Pricing: https://www.fullcontact.com/developer/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get that action from? Was it from the LinkedIn Connector perhaps? If so,  you might be lacking authentication. Check the documentation from available in the sample eSpace.

Comment: tomorow I will add that information. And I will check the documentation you said. But I think that It wasnt from LinkedIn Connector because it is not a connector it only shows your profiles from a lot social networks. But tomorow I will add more information and check better the situation

Comment: Does this prints help ?  [link](http://i.imgur.com/k81EKyo.png) and this one [link](http://i.imgur.com/1DM9KjD.png)

Comment: Id does. I can see that you have the Facebook connector installed. You probably have also a module called FacebookConnectorDemo where the usage of the previous is explained. If the "FullContact is not working, maybe it's not useing the connector properly. Aren't you able to contact the FullContact developer?